# [Appium]Performing touch action on Google Calendar using Ruby

Tags: android, ruby, google-calendar-api, appium

I have switched on ruby language and automating an application where I need to set an Event on Google Calendar.

Now, I am setting the position for the screen to select Timing for any Date.

But with this approach, on different screen size, it selects different Time and Date [as on different screen size, position also changes].

Any idea for the different approach to tackle this issue?

Let me know if any more details needed.

Comment: You can use the Google Calendar API, it'll be much more stable than an automated browser for this.

Comment: @maxpleaner I am not sure how to use it while automating a native mobile application. I`ll thankful if you elaborate a bit.